# Javascript onChange event not firing in Input type file

Tags: jquery

I am using javascript file inside the 'Scripts' folder for checking validation such file size then uploading image. However, sometimes the `change` event is not firing. What is the mistake in my code?

```js
var fileLogo = "";

$(document).on("change", "#idfileLogo", function(e) {
  var file_size = $(this)[0].files[0].size;
  if (file_size > 1000141) {
    $("#txtfileLogo").attr("placeholder", "Upload Image");
    var message = "Image size is greater than 1MB.";
    showErrormesssage(message);
    return false;
  }
  fileLogo = $(this).val();
  var ext = fileLogo.split('.').pop();
  if (ext == "x-png" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "gif" || ext == "jpg") {
    $("#txtfileLogo").attr('placeholder', $(this).val().split('\\').pop());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style="height: 35px !important" id="txtfileLogo" class="form-control input-lg" disabled placeholder="Upload Image">
<div class="input-group-btn">
  <div class="browse btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Browse<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="idfileLogo" name="fileUploadLogo" class="file"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use id selector in jquery? `$("#idfileLogo").on("change",function(e){ /* Code goes here*/});`

Comment: @Kartal : id selector also not working. So I tried this.

Answer (score 0):

you have this problem because your scripts are before your html tags and when your scripts have been run there is no "idfileLogo" tag.

put those after html tags or use jQuery event to insure your content has been loaded. for example:

```
    var fileLogo = "";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("change", "#idfileLogo", function(e) {
          var file_size = $(this)[0].files[0].size;
          if (file_size > 1000141) {
            $("#txtfileLogo").attr("placeholder", "Upload Image");
            var message = "Image size is greater than 1MB.";
            showErrormesssage(message);
            return false;
          }
          fileLogo = $(this).val();
          var ext = fileLogo.split('.').pop();
          if (ext == "x-png" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "gif" || ext == "jpg") {
            $("#txtfileLogo").attr('placeholder', $(this).val().split('\\').pop());
          }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have to write this js code inside html page or in .js file?

Comment: I have tried both of them, but still that bug raising. 1st try) I have added more than 1mb size image, then it showing error message as popup window. 2nd try) added less than 1mb image, it workng. 3rd try) again added more than 1mb size image, still it showing error message. But 4th try) again added more than 1mb size image, there the issue raising. Actually issue is functionality are working well here but the popup window and debugger not firing inside OnChange at the 4th step test. How can I solve this?

Comment: because you don't implement showErrormesssage function.

Comment: Excuse me! I have tried even alert(message). Still not showing alert at the 4th step.